# Haskell - Homework - concatenating two lists

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I am given an array of Char and have to translate it to Moves (as shown below)

```
data Move = N | S | W | E | X
newtype Moves = Moves [Move]

createMoves:: [Char]-> Moves
createMoves (x:xs) =  if xs==[] then Moves [createMove(x)]
                      else Moves [createMove (x)] 

createMove:: Char-> Move
createMove (x) = if x=='N' then N
                 else if x=='S' then S
                 else if x=='W' then W
                 else if x=='E' then                      
                 else X
```

However, I am only succeeding in getting the first item of the list.  I have tried a number of ways to make createMoves recursive but I can't get it right.  Could you please guide me?

Comment: you should format your code...

Comment: Functions don't need parentheses in Haskell. You should just write "createMove x".

Comment: BTW, this `[Char]` is **not** an array. It is a *list*.

Comment: To elaborate, what amindfv said: You neither need them nor should write them, as they may introduce subtile changes to the meaning of your program. For instance `createMove (x:xs)` is different from `createMove x:xs`, as the `:` has a lower precedence than `createMove`.

Comment: @FUZxxl, that's the absence of parentheses which is causing problems, not presence. There is nothing wrong with putting redundant parentheses while you are not yet confident with operator precedence.

Answer (score 3):

Branches of your `if` statement are the same, so it does nothing.

When programming recursive functions, there are two cases.
The basic one, you should declare `createMoves [] = []`.
The recursive is a little more complicated; basically, for each `x` you create a move that is the first element appended to a list built using a recursive call on `xs`.

A simpler way is to use the `map` function. You can also look at its implementation.
By the way, for `createMove` you could use pattern matching instead of many `if`s.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, but it is interfering with the type signature.  I am trying to implement it this way:

createMoves:: [Char]-> Moves
createMoves (x:xs) =  if xs==[] then Moves [createMove(x)]
   else createMoves(xs): Moves [createMove(x)]

Comment: The reason you're having a problem with the type signature is that you're putting the "Moves" type constructor in the recursive function. If you didn't get type problems, the list would look like this: Moves [N, Moves E, Moves S]. You simply want Moves [N, E, S].

Comment: Replace `newtype Moves = Moves [Move]` by `newtype Moves = [Move]`, it will simplify your code and you won't need the constructor everytime you make a list of moves.

Comment: @Chris - do you mean `type Moves = [Move]`?

Comment: @John: yep, forgot to remove the new

Comment: @Chris and John L.  First aof all thanks for your suggestions.  Secondly, I added the constructor as I had to add the type Moves to the show class, and if I remove the constructor the error "Cannot use type synonym in instance head" comes up.

Comment: @Annabel: `[a]` is already an instance of `Show` whenever `a` is, so as long as you have an instance for `Move` you can just remove the one for `Moves` and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be centering on combining the result of the recursive call on `xs` with the result of `createMove x`. So, let's just introduce a helper function which is going to take care of that!

```
createMoves:: [Char]-> Moves
createMoves (x:xs) =  if xs==[] then Moves [createMove x]
                      else createHelper (createMove x) (createMoves xs)
```

Now, what should the type of `createHelper` be? Its first argument is a `Move` and the second is a `Moves`, and it should put the first argument in front of the list of `Move`s contained in the second, and 'repack' it in a value of type `Moves`. To get at the list of `Move`s you need to use pattern matching, like so:

```
createHelper :: Move -> Moves -> Moves
createHelper m (Moves ms) = Moves (m:ms)
```

That should do the trick, but all this matching on the `Moves` constructor and then reapplying it is a bit silly, and potentially inefficient. A better approach is to convert the `[Char]` one-by-one to `[Move]` and only at the end tacking the `Moves` constructor on. That leads to something like (still in keeping with your original idea):

```
createMoves :: [Char] -> Moves
createMoves cs = Moves (createMoveList cs)

createMoveList :: [Char] -> [Move]
createMoveList (x:xs) = if xs == [] then [] else createMove x : createMoveList xs
```

`createMoveList` is a pattern that comes up very often in Haskell, namely that of applying a function (in this case, `createMove`) to each element in a list. This is the essence of the `map` function (which I'm sure you'll get to very soon in your lessons, if you haven't already!).

If you use that, you can also get rid of the problem that `createMoves` fails when given an empty list. So the solution I would go with is:

```
createMoves :: [Char] -> Moves
createMoves cs = Moves (map createMove cs)
```

or

```
createMoves = Moves . map createMove
```

but that's another story!

Comment: Great answer! +1 for not trying to fix anything that is not broken. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your createMoves function only operates on one element of the list it's given.

Try using the `map` function. On other words, start your function with:

```
createMoves list = Moves (map
```

[...]

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to use Guards (i.e. `|`) instead of `if`, `then` and `else`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should remove the `newtype` statement; if you want the list to print, just have the `Move` type derive `Show`.

Next, you can remove the explicit recursion in the `createMoves` function by using `map`. For future reference, you can look for functions by name and type signature on [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

Finally, you can use pattern matching to eliminate all the equality tests against constants. An irrelevant example using the `Move` type is

```
isN :: Move -> Bool
isN N = True
isN _ = False
```

Note that the `_` character means "ignore this value". If you haven't covered pattern matching yet, then guards might still be better than nested `if`s.